# Inaccurate value matching in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the data.table (data.table_1.9.4) package and have noticed that it erroneously matches large integers in searches. For example, I use

```
edgelist_subs[refId==511342051002]
```

and get the following response

```
structure(list(A1 = c(108885L, 206052L, 202L, 108885L, 206052L, 
222217L, 206052L, 202L, 108885L, 206052L, 206052L, 206052L, 485681L
), A2 = c(202L, 202L, 8654L, 8654L, 8654L, 8654L, 108885L, 222217L, 
222217L, 222217L, 485681L, 531081L, 531081L), refId = c(511342051002, 
511342051002, 511342051002, 511342051002, 511342051002, 511342051002, 
511342051002, 511342051002, 511342051002, 511342051002, 511342051003, 
511342051003, 511342051003), year = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L
)), .Names = c("A1", "A2", "refId", "year"), sorted = c("A2", 
"A1"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2f54de8>)
```

notice where the refIds do not match the searched refId exactly, but are all off on the last digit. Is there any way to work around this problem without having to renumber the id's to make them smaller?

Comment: Can you just treat the IDs as character values rather than numeric values?

Comment: I get an error with the `dput`

Comment: @PierreLafortune Yeah, I hit this frequently with data.tables. My workaround is overwriting the selfref thing with NULL and then running setDT on it. Not sure what one should do, though.

Comment: I agree with MrFlick. Don't store IDs as floating point numbers and you'll be fine.

Comment: _especially_ when the IDs are more than (ROT) 5 digits long

Comment: Thanks @Frank. And OP always check for leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: this seems to be working too: `df[floor(refId)==511342051002]` because as it says in the documentation `floor takes a single numeric argument x and returns a numeric vector containing the largest integers not greater than the corresponding elements of x.`

Comment: @LyzandeR that's not why it works - it works for the same reason the `TRUE &` trick works in my answer below

Comment: Thanks @eddi . What qualifies as a more complex expression? Even this seems to work: `df[refId + 0 == 511342051002]`. Does it mean anything more than the single equality?

Comment: @LyzandeR hard to say, at the moment I think only simple `a == b` and `a %in% b` type expressions are parsed, but that could change in the future

Comment: I see. Thanks @eddi You are right about this

Comment: In this particular case I have > 1 million unique cases, and make frequent use of the numeric properties in loops and such. I have also kept the ids because doing so allows me to reference the id's in our database, which were created for specific reasons. I tried coercing the ids to double, but that didn't work.  Instead I added a new column in the DB with new id's starting from 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to understand that those are **not** integers. Those are floating point numbers.

Second, since 1.9.4 `data.table` uses binary search for simple comparison linear searches, like the one you have, and to do a binary search with floating point numbers you generally want some rounding. It so happens that the default level of rounding makes your IDs equal.

There are many solutions to your issue (listed in my order of preference): use 64-bit integers, use character id's, change the rounding, disable secondary indexing/trick it. The first two should be self-explanatory, and here are the last two options:

```
# disabling secondary indexing, by making expression more complicated
# or directly change the option - options(datatable.auto.index=FALSE)
dt[TRUE & refId == 511342051002]

# adjust rounding (default is 2)
setNumericRounding(1)
dt[refId == 511342051002]
```

Comment: Factors don't make your list? I'm guessing the OP doesn't actually need 64-bit integers and has far fewer than 511342051002 unique Ids (in case that would matter... never seen a need for big ints in my work).

Comment: I didn't think of them - theoretically they are a good option, in practice, I hate and never use factors, which is why I didn't think of them.

Comment: I, too, am not a fan of factors. I tried coercing the column to double, but that didn't work. BTW, using 64 bit integers does not seem to be part of the base package of R? I was curious as to whether or not the data.table package can take advantage of secondary packages using larger integers?

Comment: `data.table` is designed to play well with `bit64` package which provides 64-bit integer support